# Why am I getting 100% cpu on "osemgrep lsp --experimental"?

Tags: lsp-mode

I'm on NixOS and I frequently have to kill this process

```
osemgrep lsp --experimental
```

I don't even have that executable in my path; I have semgrep, though.

I also can't find any reference to it in my configuration.

I see that it runs with an experimental flag. Maybe I can try to remove that if I find the configuration for it?;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this in any way related to Emacs?

Comment: Well, it's Emacs that triggers this process and it's also the one instructing it to use the --experimental flag, I assume and it's also the one who can tell it to not use said flag, I would assume.

Comment: Then could you provide a simple recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`, to reproduce the actual problem?